# How to crop a WebView screen capture?

Tags: android, webview

I would like to take a screenshot of my WebView, then crop it at x,y,w,h.  Here is what I got:

```
private WebView mWebView;
public void onSavePhoto(int top, int left, int width, int height){
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWebView.getWidth(), mWebView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    mWebView.draw(canvas);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crop using [createBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

```
private WebView mWebView;
public void onSavePhoto(int top, int left, int width, int height){
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWebView.getWidth(), mWebView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    mWebView.draw(canvas);

    // crop bitmap:
    Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, left, top, width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with these steps

1. Create a new bitmap that is the dimensions you want
2. Use [drawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint)) to copy the section you want from the original bitmap to the new one